# Selenium python: Difficulty Switching to frame on this page

Tags: python, selenium

I am finding it difficult to switch to iframe and click on O/U on this page. I need help with this guys!
Here is my code below;

```
    from random import *
    import random
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    driver.get("https://www.sportybet.com/ke/sporty-instant-virtuals/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    instantplay= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Instant Virtuals']")
    instantplay.click()
    # find the frame
    frame2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='instantwin-sport']")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame2)
    time.sleep(3)
    # Click O/U
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[text()[normalize-space()='O/U']]")
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never click on the element. Add .click() after finding the element.
You can also remove the sleep before the iframe and put an implicit wait to wait on the O/U button

```
driver.get("https://www.sportybet.com/ke/sporty-instant-virtuals/")
driver.maximize_window()

instantplay= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Instant Virtuals']")
instantplay.click()
# find the frame
frame2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='instantwin-sport']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame2)
# Click O/U
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[text()[normalize-space()='O/U']]").click()
```